# pass data from child to parent inside of router-outlet

Tags: angular

I have a parent component with a router-outlet. I want to call the parent function with a child event. I understand @Input() and @Output, but how do you use them with router-outlet

```
<router-outlet (tapVocab)="openVocabModal($event)"></router-outlet>
```

Doesn't seem to work for me. In my child I have:

```
@Output() tapVocab = new EventEmitter<string>();

callParent(val) {
    console.log('calling parent', val);
    this.tapVocab.next(val);
  }
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

From [angular](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterOutlet)

> `<router-outlet>` Acts as a placeholder that Angular dynamically fills
>   based on the current router state.

`<router-outlet>` does not offer a means to bind data to loaded components or emit events from them to parents.

But it has two events:

activate — emits any time a new component is instantiated.

deactivate — emits when the component is destroyed.

```
<router-outlet (activate)="componentAdded($event)" (deactivate)="componentRemoved($event)"></router-outlet>
```

But I don't think it will be useful for your case.

But you can communicate like any other communication between two unrelated components using service.

common.service.ts:

```
@Injectable()
export class CommonService {
  private data = new BehaviorSubject('default data');
  data$ = this.data.asObservable();

  changeData(data: string) {
    this.data.next(data)
  }
}
```

app.component.ts:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-component',
  template: `<p>{{data}}</p>`
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  data: string;

  constructor(private service: CommonService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.service.data$.subscribe(res => this.data = res)  //read the invoked data or default data
  }

}
```

child.component.ts:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-component-two',
  template: `
    <p>{{data}}</p>
    <button (click)="newData()">Next Data</button>`
})
export class ComponentTwoComponent implements OnInit {

  data: string;

  constructor(private service: CommonService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.service.data$.subscribe(res => this.data = res)
  }
  newData() {
    this.service.changeData('Changed Data');  //invoke new Data
  }
}
```

Comment: Very helpful. I would only say, since the property data is private to the service, you can't call this.service.data.next on it in the child component, you have to use the changeData() method instead.

Comment: It was a mistake, I made that changeData() function for this reason. Updated the answer

Comment: Will it work the same way if I change the data in the parent component?

Comment: The event binding `(activate)` can actually be used to achieve this. You just have to initialize a public variable in your child component. Though this might not be most robust solution.

Answer (score 0):

Components loaded using router-outlet couldn't be handled as ones injected in the template using input/output mechanism.

You need to implement a shared service, this service should provide a Stream of communication between Parent and Child.

example:

```js
@Injectable()
export class MyService{

  private data$: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();

  next(data:any):void {
    this.data$.next(data);
  }

  select(): Observable<any> {
    this.data$.asObservable();
  }

}
```

you need know to inject this service into your components and watch/push data throw it

Comment: Thank you for the help. This is a similar answer to above and is the solution.